# openerp login access denied

Tags: openerp-7, postgresql-9.4

I am getting error while login in OpenERP

Access Denied

The requested operation cannot be completed due to security restrictions. Please contact your system administrator.

(Document type: Users, Operation: read)

**NOTE**
i dont have create the user from user module but I insert the data in user table in database.

for admin it is working fine also it is fine with the user created from OpenERP user module

**Showing error only for those user which I insert from database directly**

Please help me friends....Your help will highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

In your res_users table check that the active boolean is true.